# ToolTwist Controller hangs while generating images

Tags: imagemagick, tooltwist

While generating a large site using the ToolTwist Controller, the server hangs. Using ps -ef I can see that there is an ImageMagick 'convert' command that never seems to finish. If I kill the convert process, the generate continues.

If I get the full convert command from the log file or using ps, I can run it from the command line with no problem. Each time I run the generate process in the Controller it gets stuck in a different place.

How often it hangs seems to be sporadic, and only occurs maybe every 1,000 images.

I'm running OSX 10.7.3 on a Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in ImageMagick - see http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=19962

The solution is to define an environment variable:
    export MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT=1

You'll need to do this before starting the Controller's tomcat server.